# vb.net dynamic plugin loading question

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the following code in a vb.net 2008 project to dynamically load dll's (with forms) from a folder, all works great however I can't figure out for the life of me how to call a function or get a public variable from the plugins.

Can anyone answer this issue for me?

```
Dim PluginList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(appDir, "*.dll")

For Each Plugin As String In PluginList

    Dim Asm As Assembly
    Dim SysTypes As System.Type
    Asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(Plugin)
    SysTypes = Asm.GetType(Asm.GetName.Name + ".frmMain")
    Dim IsForm As Boolean = GetType(Form).IsAssignableFrom(SysTypes)
    If IsForm Then
            Dim tmpForm As Form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(SysTypes), Form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create an interface in a common assembly and have your form implement it, this way you can cast you dynamically loaded object as your interface type.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Plugin.Interfaces

Sub Main()
    Dim assembly As Assembly
    assembly = assembly.LoadFrom("Plugin.X.dll")

    Dim type As Type
    Dim found As Boolean = False

    For Each type In assembly.GetTypes()
        If GetType(IForm).IsAssignableFrom(type) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If found Then
        Dim instance As IForm
        instance = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(type), IForm)

        Console.WriteLine(instance.Add(20, 20))
    End If
End Sub
```

Interface Assembly

```
Public Interface IForm
    Function Add(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
End Interface
```

Plugin Assembly

```
Imports Plugin.Interfaces

Public Class Form
    Implements IForm

    Public Function Add(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer Implements IForm.Add
        Return x + y
    End Function

End Class
```